# Metrics getting reset after restarting dataflow pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a streaming pipeline in cloud-dataflow, where I set `Metrics.counter` as below.

```java
class SomeDoFn extends DoFn {
  val validIdCounter = Metrics.counter("user-type", "valid_ids")
  val invalidIdCounter = Metrics.counter("user-type", "invalid_ids")

  @ProcessElement
  def process(c: ProcessContext): Unit = {   
    val userId = getId(c.element) match {
    case Success(id) => 
      validIdCounter.inc()
      Some(id)
    case Failure(e) =>   
      invalidIdCounter.inc()
      None
    }
   ...
 }
```

I'm able to see the metrics in Stackdriver monitoring and create alert for the same. But when I restart the pipeline, the metrics become zero. Is it the expected behaviour? Is there a way I can preserve the metrics across jobs and job runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metric count resetting to zero is the expected behavior. To preserve the total metric count in Stackdriver, use count aggregation when charting the metric.